# Change (map) JSON list shape - add tag to objects in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, dictionary, tags

I am trying to change in my Angular (TypeScript) project a JSON list received through a REST request.

*The* **initial JSON** *looks like this:*

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "position":3,
      "articleNumber":6
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "position":2,
      "articleNumber":7
   }
]
```

I need it to **become**:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "data":{  
            "id":1,
            "position":3,
            "articleNumber":6
         }
      },
      {  
         "children":[  
            {  
               "data":{  
                  "id":2,
                  "position":2,
                  "articleNumber":7
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I managed to add the '**data**' tag by creating a new object { data: } and then assign to data property the result of array.map.

```
const mapped = { data: array.map(item => ({ data: item }))};
```

As a result, i get this:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "data":{  
            "id":1,
            "position":3,
            "articleNumber":6
         }
      },
      {  
         "data":{  
            "id":2,
            "position":2,
            "articleNumber":7
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I add the '**children**' tag too, which may contain many '*data*'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on this logic:

```
let array = [  {  
  "id":1,
  "position":3,
  "articleNumber":6},{  
  "id":2,
  "position":2,
  "articleNumber":7}];

const mapped1 = { data: array[0]};
const mapped2 = { children: array.map((item, index) => ({ data: item }))} ;
const final = {data:[mapped1]};

final.data.push(mapped2);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

import { Response } from '@angular/http';

in your service:   `.map((item: Response) => item.json());`

Now, in your controller(component.ts) use `.subscribe()`, you will get the object as it is in JSON.